# Ubuntu 22.04 loses internet connection randomly

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet

I have a problem with Ubuntu 22.04 running on a Dell XPS 9520. The PC normally connects to my home Wi-Fi but after some time - which may vary from a few minutes to several hours - it loses the connection and there is no way to connect it back without having to reboot the system. When this happens, instead of the Wi-Fi icon on the top right corner a question mark is shown. Here are two screenshots of what I see:

After losing connection:

[image: after losing connection]

After losing connection:

[image: after losing connection]

Sometimes it detects only a few networks and tries to reconnect to the one it was previously connected to without success. The same happens when I try to connect it to my phone's hotspot.

I've been experiencing this problem for a few days now and I've had difficulties finding a solution online by querying Google. Is there anyone who can suggest what I can do, at least to diagnose the problem?

Comment: Just upgraded to 22.04. Also happened to me like randomly. But the case is when I close the lid and open again, I thought it was my internet.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. When I encountered this problem sometime early this year, I used to fix it with these:

1. Run the command: sudo lshw -class netwok
   Get the product id something. In my case, something like this: RTL812xE
2. Navigate to config file: cd /etc/pm/sleep.d
3. Edit the file by adding this: SUSPEND_MODULES="RTL812xE"
   3.1 Save and exit
4. Run this command: echo "options RTL812xE fwlps=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/RTL812xE.conf
5. Reboot by running the command in the terminal: reboot

When I followed and did these procedures, my network connection would resume to work properly. Now, I tried to do these several times but it is no longer working. I am still looking for a way to fix this as I do not want to re-install my ubuntu os.

Comment: Hi @mandudeman, I was trying this. But, on the first step, I didn't get any product id. It looks like this "Wireless 8265 / 8275". Is this "Wireless" product id?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, it will randomly cut off for me too. You could try this solution, but I made these changes and restarted and still have the same issue. Also running on a Dell

--Disable Wi-Fi Powersave
Run 'sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf'
Ctrl + X
Change value to '2'
Type 'y'
Press Enter
Exit

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if this happens with other distros too?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem twice. In both cases it was solved by forgetting the wifi connection and then setting it up again, identically as before. In the first case, which was at a hotel, I did this more or less directly. In the second case I was at an institute and had access to another wifi network (physical the same but not eduroam). But after it hadn't resolved itself for about a week I forgot the eduroam connection and set it up again as before. And now it is working.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1267168)